# Understanding Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

People use `Backbone.View` in many ways, and I'm kind of confused. I have seen:

```
Backbone.View.extend({});
new Backbone.View.extend({});
new Backbone.View();
new Backbone.View;
```

The first three are *different*. The last two are the same. (See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z34/) for a Fiddle.) What is happening in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all the same thing.

When you exetend a class using `Backbone.View.extend({})`, as you can see, you are not adding any aditional property or method to your class. You're passing it an empty hash `{}` as argument. So, `Backbone.View` and `Backbone.View.extend({})` are pretty much the same thing.

About the `new` keyword presence before, it just instanciate a new class. When you don't use the `new` keyword, you're just talking about classes, whereas with the `new` keyword, you are talking about an object of this very same class.

Parentesis are not an obligation. It is only required if you want to pass arguments to its constructor, so `new Backbone.View()` and `new Backbone.View;` are the same, just like `new Backbone.View()` and `new Backbone.View.extend({})`, for the reasons I wrote before.

About this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z34/):

- `myView1` is a class which extends View
- `myView2` (with parentesis as in my fiddle) is an object of a class extended of Backbone.View
- `myView3` is an object of Backbone.View class. It is not extended.
- `myView4` the same as `myView3`

Comment: `Backbone.View` and `Backbone.View.extend()` are *different*. Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z34/1/).

Comment: (can't run the Fiddle examples, so I used my Chrome console)
@gustavotkg is still right.
The console tells you that the first three are different. However `Backbone.View` and `Backbone.View.extend()` are similar. Using `new Backbone.View` and `new (Backbone.View.extend())` both call the View constructor and return similar objects, though `Backbone.View.extend()` takes a detour through the function it returns[inherits, in line 1096].

`new Backbone.View.extend()`, note the missing brackets, is more or less a JSWTF. I'd expect it to call `new (Backbone.View.extend())` and it doesn't.

Comment: @wieczo: Thanks. Your comment about the brackets is very helpful. I was confused about that.

Comment: @wieczo I agree with you, about the JSWTF part.

Answer (score -1):

Extend creates a subclass. In your examples you do not add any custom code so the viewclasses behave exactly like the original backbone views. With the new keyword you call the constructor function of your class which returns an instance of a view.
So if you want to have custom Code in a view eg. with a render function you extend BB view. Then when you want to use this view you create a new instance of your extended view.

Comment: I'm confused. `new Backbone.View.extend({});` does *not* return an instance. It returns a function.

Comment: This may be because this statement confuses the order of method calls. You will rarely need this combined statement as you can only create one instance of the extended class. Calling: new (Backbone.View.extend({})) should work as expected.

Comment: A new statement in front of a method call eg: "new hello();" will not execute the function call but use the method as a constructor function of a new object that is been created via new. So your extend function is then used as the constructor function of a completely new object. This is not JSWTF because in JS functions are objects (and therefore classes) as well so calling new is creating a new instance of it.